# How can I fake a physics simulation with variations between two predetermined points in Phaser 3?

Tags: javascript, game-physics, phaser-framework

I want to fake a simulation of a golf shot between the origin (where the ball lies), and a known result of the destination (where the shot finishes). I am determining the destination of the shot first with a random number. After that, I want to randomize a shot shape within certain bounds to make it interesting.

Is it possible to work backwards with arcade physics?

My current solution is to enumerate many paths before and then to randomly choose one. The problem with this strategy is that the distance of the shot can vary, so this greatly increases the amount of predetermined paths needed.

Comment: Are you thinking about a side-on view with "arcade" physics? Something like: https://labs.phaser.io/edit.html?src=src\physics\arcade\velocity%20from%20angle.js

Comment: Would be isometric and head-on, but the vector is not the issue. It's the logic of doing it realistically without enumerating that has me stumped. I guess could reverse different types of rollouts and then randomize looking back, but I have no solution yet for actual physics.